# Asymptotic behavior of $R(4,k)$.

Tags: proof-explanation, asymptotics, approximation, estimation, ramsey-theory

I’m struggling to understand a step in the application of the following formula to a specific case.

> THEOREM. If
> $$\binom{n}{k}p^\tbinom{k}{2}+\binom{n}{t}(1-p)^\tbinom{t}{2}<1$$
> for some $p \in[0,1],$ then $R(k, t)>n$

> Let us examine the asymptotics of $R(4, t) .$ We want $\binom{n}{4}p^{6}=c n^{4} p^{6}<1$ so we take $p=\varepsilon n^{-2 / 3}$. Now we estimate $\binom{n}{t}$ by $n^{t}(!), 1-p$ by $e^{-p}$ and $\binom{t}{2}$ by $t^{2} / 2,$ so
> we want $n^{t} e^{-p t^{2} / 2}<1 .$ Taking $t$-th roots and $\operatorname{logs}, p t / 2>\ln n$ and $t>(2 / p) \ln n=$
> $K n^{2 / 3} \ln n .$ Expressing $n$ in terms of $t$
> $$
> R(4, t)>k t^{3 / 2} / \ln ^{3 / 2} t=t^{3 / 2+o(1)}
> $$

What happens at that part “expressing $n$ in terms of $t$”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before that part, we've used the theorem you've quoted to show that $R(4,t) > n$ provided that $t > K n^{2/3} \ln n$.

We want to show that there is a $k$ such that $n < k (\frac{t}{\ln t})^{3/2}$, then $t > K n^{2/3} \ln n$.

Well, if $n < k (\frac{t}{\ln t})^{3/2}$, then (for $t$ large enough, specifically $t \ge e^{k^{2/3}}$) we also have $n < t^{3/2}$, so $\frac23\ln n < \ln t$. This gives us
$$
  \frac23n^{2/3}\ln n <  k^{2/3} \left(\frac{t}{\ln t}\right) \ln t = k^{2/3}t \implies \frac{2}{3k^{2/3}} n^{2/3}\ln n < t
$$
and we get the inequality we want when we take $k = (3K/2)^{-3/2}$, which gives $\frac{2}{3k^{2/3}} = K$.

We conclude that $R(4,t) > n$ for every $n$ such that $n < k(\frac{t}{\ln t})^{3/2}$; in other words, $R(2,t) \ge k(\frac{t}{\ln t})^{3/2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a few further questions if you don’t mind: 1. I want to see where we’d have $n < t$, so I plot $k \left( \frac{t}{\text{ln }t}\right)^{3/2} - t$ with the parameter $k$ here: https://imgur.com/d0ionsP, and see where it’s negative. Am I correct to assume that of course we can select $t$ as large as we want, but in such case we might have to get smaller $k$ so that we’d have $n < t$?

Comment: 2. I’m not sure I understand your last conclusion. We have $R(4,t) > n$ provided that $n < k \left( \frac{t}{\text{ln }t}\right)^{3/2}$. What if $R(4,t)$ falls somewhere between $n$ and $k\left(\frac{t}{\ln\left(t\right)}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$? How can we conclude that $R(4,t) > k\left(\frac{t}{\ln\left(t\right)}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ then? In my mind I was looking for a lower bound of $n$ in terms of $t$, so that the quoted theorem could be applied. This analysis doesn’t seem to apply here.

Comment: 3. I realize that I’m actually not sure about the part that is “before that part”. How is making ${n \choose 4}p^6 < 1$ and ${n \choose t}(1-p)^{t \choose 2} < 1$ enough to make their sum less than $1$? Shouldn’t the RHS’ be $0.5$ or something?

Comment: For 1 and 2, I've edited my answer to address your questions (I actually got the inequality backwards for question 1, so see the edit - it should make more sense now). For point 3, you are right that the RHS should be something like $\frac12$ and they're being sloppy, but being more precise about that would only affect the constants, which we don't see anyway.

Comment: Very sorry but I still can’t get my head around the last sentence in your answer (i.e. the answer to my q2 above). The edit has made q1 more clear though.

As for q3, I realize that we can make ${n \choose 4}p^6$ as small as we’d like (say, $\frac{1}{2}$), by choosing a smaller $p$. But in that case what guarantees ${n \choose t}(1-p)^{t \choose 2}$ to be small enough so that the sum is less than $1$?

Comment: They solve $n^t e^{-pt^2/2} < 1$ for $t$; you could solve $n^t e^{-pt^2/2} < \frac12$ for $t$ instead. As for the last sentence: if you have the statement "$x$ is bigger than everything less than $100$", it implies "$x$ is at least $100$", and what's going on here is just a more general form than that.

Comment: I was thinking of a fixed $n$ and that didn’t help. Thanks for being so patient!